# How to enable GET with body on Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I found issue about this on [issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36886282) and read whole annotations part of the docs. But I'm unable to make it happen on a K8S cluster on GCP.

I know that GET with body is not a standard thing. I need to support this on the application because it was one of the existing features before we decided to move the stuff to kubernetes. So my hands are tied about this.

Comment: What is the Issue Tracker link? An HTTP GET request with body is very unusual. Design for the norm and not the exception. SO has a big thread on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: I know. I know. We ignore the body on GET req but Ingress is returning 400 when there is a body in the GET and it can break some of the webhooks that are connected to our service.

Comment: Can you post more details about your setup (GKE version, ingress config, ingress controller etc.) and link to the issue tracker?

Comment: GKE: 1.13.12-gke.25
Ingress config is nothing is special just default ones.